# Adding HashMap to marker to display image doesn't return the correct image for that specific marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am going to try and explain this in much detail as possible (if i miss anything please let me know)

So in my app on the map the user can longclick at any point on the map, which then adds a default marker and it starts the camera intent, whereby the user can take a photo of the castle and return to the map.  so when the user then taps on the map the full image is displayed in the `getInfoContents(Marker marker)` and when the user taps on the `infoWindow` they can either select "delete marker" or "cancel"  All of this is fine and working.  However the problem i am facing is when the user takes a photo of castle 1 and places the marker, and then take another photo of castle 2 and places the marker, what seem to happen is that when tapping on castle 1 marker, castle 2 image is displayed (the same then for castle 2)

So what i would like to do is "save" that image to that specific marker.

So this is my code up until this point:

I created the HashMap:

```
private HashMap<Bitmap, Marker> myMarkersHash;
```

Then in `onCreate` method this:

```
myMarkersHash = new HashMap<Bitmap, Marker>();
```

Then in `onMapLongClick` this:

```
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
       .position(thePoint));
myMarkersHash.put(bitmap, marker);
```

Then in my `getInfoContents(Marker marker)` this:

```
View v  = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);
final ImageView markerIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.marker_icon);
myMarkersHash.get(bitmap);
markerIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

But this doesn't seem to work, so am missing something here I think.

This is my camera intent (Might help with my question)

```
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "My Castle");
imagesFolder.mkdirs();
image = new File(imagesFolder, "Mycastle_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
startActivityForResult(imageIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

Then in `onActivityResult` this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

 try {
 GetImageThumbnail getImageThumbnail = new GetImageThumbnail();
 bitmap = getImageThumbnail.getThumbnail(fileUri, this);
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

(Just to add the `onActivityResult` gets the scaled down image from the `GetImageThumbnail.class`

Hope i have made sense and really hoping some one could assist me with this problem.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT 1**

So what i have tried now is to implement this:

```
private Map<String, Uri> myMarkersHash;
```

the in `onCreate` Method:

```
myMarkersHash = new HashMap<String, Uri>();
```

Then in `onMapLongClick` this:

```
myMarkersHash.put(marker.getId(), fileUri );
```

And finally `getInfoContents` this:

```
 myMarkersHash.get(marker.getId() + fileUri);
 markerIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

But unfortunately it still doesn't seem to work.  I have also tried `image.getAbsolutePath();` but that just crashes the app with a `nullPointerException`

**EDIT 2**

As suggested i have tried this:

```
private Map<String, Bitmap> myMarkersHash;
```

the in `onCreate` Method:

```
myMarkersHash = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
```

Then in `onMapLongClick` this:

```
myMarkersHash.put(marker.getId(), bitmap);
```

And finally `getInfoContents` this:

```
 myMarkersHash.get(marker.getId());
 markerIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

But still doesn't seem to work, still displaying the same image for every marker.  I think that it doesn't see that image taken at that point (although the images are saved to a folder on the sdCard if that makes sense?)

**EDIT 3**

Okay so there is light at the end of the tunnel!  However not quite there yet.  As suggested i have implemented this code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = myMarkersHash.get(marker.getId());
markerIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Now what seems to happen is this:

a. 1st marker placed  =  no image

b. 2nd marker placed  =  image of the first marker

c. 3rd marker placed  =  image of the 2nd marker

d. 4th marker placed  =  image of the 3rd marker

e. 5th marker placed  =  image of the 4th marker

and so forth.

Any ideas why this would happen?  Will try something now and let you know.

**EDIT 4**

Full `OnMapLongClick` code:

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
    thePoint=point;

    Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(thePoint));
    myMarkersHash.put(marker.getId(), bitmap );

     Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
     File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "My Castle");
     imagesFolder.mkdirs();
     image = new File(imagesFolder.getPath(), "Mycastle_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
     fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);

     imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
     startActivityForResult(imageIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT 5**

GREAT!! it works!! Whoop,  but the problem is it is turning an image taken in portrait to landscape,  which is why i had to implement this code:

```
ExifInterface exif = null;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(image.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
           if (orientation != 1) {
                   switch (orientation) {
                   case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                       rotate = 90;
                       break;
                   case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                       rotate = 180;
                       break;
                   case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                       rotate = 270;
                       break;
                   default:
                       rotate = 0;
                       break;
                   }
           }
           Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(rotate);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),  bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
           }
        }
```

But since adding the code as suggested, its gone back to displaying the photo taken in portrait to landscape.

**LAST EDIT**

Okay so all is working now a 100%!!  Thanks for all the help, much appreciated!!!

Comment: Have you tried `myMarkersHash.get(marker.getId())` ? I don't see why you are using `myMarkersHash.get(marker.getId() + fileUri)` which is probably returning null in that case.

You should also probably use a `HashMap<String, Bitmap>();` to get the bitmap directly from the markerId.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, unfortunately that didn't work.  I have updated my question with your suggestion. (am trying to keep track of what i have tried and not, because i have tried so many different ways. :-)

Comment: Not sure what is the purpose of your hashmap, why dont you just put the file url as the value and marker id as the key in your hashmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure from your edit of what you are exactly doing, but it seems you're not using HashMap as you would need to. You might try something like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = myMarkersHash.get(marker.getId());
markerIcon.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

You should also create a local bitmap before adding it to the HashMap:

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
    thePoint=point;

    Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(thePoint));
     markerId = marker.getId();         

     Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
     File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "My Castle");
     imagesFolder.mkdirs();
     image = new File(imagesFolder.getPath(), "Mycastle_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
     fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);

     imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
     startActivityForResult(imageIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}
```

Then when you set your bitmap:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

 try {
 GetImageThumbnail getImageThumbnail = new GetImageThumbnail();
 Bitmap bitmap = getImageThumbnail.getThumbnail(fileUri, this);
 myMarkersHash.put(markerId, bitmap );
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Therefore, you need to store your markerId somewhere to be able to get it in onActivityResult

Comment: Right,  There is light at the end of the tunnel!! however have updated my question with the results.

Comment: Can you provide the full onMapLongClick code (updated) please ? It sounds like the bitmap is not added with the right markerId

Comment: I've updated my answer. The thing is you are not setting the bitmap that is added to the HashMap I think.

Comment: Just curious, why you put a null bitmap to the hasmap, and why dont you just save the image file url as a value for the hashmap.

Comment: I just thought it might be easier for wemapps to add  a Bitmap instead of the image file as he wants to deal with Bitmap after. My bad for the null bitmap, this is useless. I removed it, thanks for noticing it

Comment: GREAT it works, but however again,  the image is displayed sideways now,  and not portrait as it was taken,  now i had the ExifInterface implemented which turned then the right way but since adding the code as suggested it turns is sideways again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating a new imagesFolder every time.

You can try to do something like:

```
File imagesFolder = new(File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "My Castle");
if (!imagesFolder.exists()) {
   if (!imagesFolder.mkdirs()) {
       Log.e(TAG, "Fail to create directory.");
       return null;
   }
}
```

And this:

```
file = new File(imageFolder.getPath() + File.seperator + "IMG_" + timestamp + ".jpg");
```

Also, you can output the list of Marker ID from your hashmap, see if the number of marker ids matched.